# how to get users address that payed using my QR code in png?

Tags: solidity, smart-contract-wallets, binance-smart-chain, qrcode

Hello i have a QR code in png containing our address where he can send any BNB. My question is how to get the users address so he gets our own token.

Comment: I understand that you want for the user to scan the QR with their mobile wallet and it will send the appropriate amount to yours. Is that so? There's [EIP-681 - URL Format for Transaction Requests](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-681).

Comment: Are you using a smart contract or just a normal address to accept payments? In the first case you could store the information in the contract, in the later case you could use the transaction history to retrieve the deposits and senders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement a fallback function in your contract. So that when BNB is deposited in your contract the fallback will be called and in fallback you can write logic to send calculated token amount to that user a.k.a, `msg.sender`.

```
contract Treasury{
 ...............
 fallback() payable{
   uint256 sentByUser = msg.value;
   uint256 requiredTokenAmount = <***your calculation logic***>
   IERC(tokenAddress).transfer(msg.sender, requiredTokenAmount);
   emit <***your event***>;
 }
 ................
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer do u know how to get the value that user sent to the contract ? so i can implement to the calculation logic

Comment: Yes, to get the eth/bnb value sent by user use the `msg.value` context
See the edit I have made in my answer